# How to change icon size dynamically to create proportional symbols map

Tags: json, leaflet, icons, marker

So I'm following this tutorial: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/781. Which is intended to create a proportional symbols map using Leaflet.

Here is my json file: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ohhd8

Here is my code:

function addCTHValue() {

```
        // function to size each icon proportionally based on CTH value

    function sizeByCTHValue(feature){
      var calculatedSize = (feature.properties.CTHValue / 3000) * 30;

      // create money icons

      return L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'money.png',
        iconSize: [calculatedSize, calculatedSize]
      });
    }

var CTHValueLayer =                 L.geoJson(CTHValue, { 
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: sizeByCTHValue(feature)
            });
        }       
});

CTHValueLayer.addTo(map);
```

}
Right now, all my icons are absolutely huge, not centred on the latlng points in my json, and I can't figure out how to properly scale the icons.

My main issue is with the following line: (feature.properties.CTHValue / 3000) * 30; These numbers are intended to signify that when the CTH value is 3000, its representative icon will be 30px across. This doesn't seem to work as my icons are much larger than 30px despite the fact that none of my CTH values even reach 3000.

Also, could I centre them on the right points with an anchor? Right now they are all crowded in the corner of my map and move around when I zoom in and out.

Can someone please help me fix my map :-)

edit: my code now looks like this:

```
  function addCTHValue() {

                CTHValueLayer = L.geoJSON(CTHValue,  {
                        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                            return new L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                            style: function stylebyCTHValue(feature) {
                            }}
                        )}
                });
                CTHValueLayer.addTo(map);
    }

    function styleByCTHValue(feature) {

                return {
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    fillColor: blue,
                    radius: (feature.properties.CTHValue / 1000) * 30
            };
        }
```

My circles are now on the map, but they are still not proportional to the CTH Value in the json. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Haven't you asked that question twice already?

Comment: yes, no one answered, so i reasked? i need to fix this issue before i can move on to anything else

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: ok so i updated with my new attempt. can u help? im still stuck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the radius of a circle marker to be proportional to an attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401891/how-to-set-the-radius-of-a-circle-marker-to-be-proportional-to-an-attribute-valu)